# How do I remove a character once from a string [python]?

Tags: python, string, replace

Is there a better way than what I am doing?

```
word = "baab"
word = word[:word.find('a')]+word[word.find('a')+1:]
print word #bab
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the string replace function with a maximum count:

```
s = s.replace('a','',1)
```

as in the following transcript:

```
>>> s = "baab"
>>> s = s.replace('a','',1)
>>> s
'bab'
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html):

> **str.replace(old, new[, count])**
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring `old` replaced by `new`. If the optional argument `count` is given, only the first `count` occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 7):

```
In[3]: "baab".replace('a', '', 1)
Out[3]: 'bab'
```

Will replace `a` only once with nothing, hence removing it.